# Python: why visiting an existing attribute triggered "__getattr__"?

Tags: python, getattr

I knew that python's `__getattr__` is triggered when visiting a non-existing attribute.

But in my example below, inside c1's `__init__`, I created a self attribute called name. When visiting it, both access ways triggered `__getattr__` and thus printed "None".

This is weird to me. I suppose either my understanding or my code has some issue?

```
$ cat n.py

class c1(object):
    def __init__(s):
        print 'init c1'
        s.name='abc'
    def __getattr__(s,name):
        print "__getattr__:"+name
        return None
    def __setattr__(s,name,value):
        print "__setattr__:"+value
    def __get__(s,inst,owner):
        print "__get__"

class d:
    def __init__(s):
        s.c=c1()

c=c1()
print c.name
o=d()
print o.c.name

$ python n.py

init c1
__setattr__:abc
__getattr__:name
None
init c1
__setattr__:abc
__getattr__:name
None
```

You can see I've defined `s.name='abc'` inside `__init__`, but it is not recognized when calling it.

Comment: Your `__setattr__` method doesn't do anything, which is why the `name` attribute isn't set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *also* implemented `__setattr__`, and it is *always* called when trying to set an attribute. Your version only prints the attribute:

```
def __setattr__(s,name,value):
    print "__setattr__:"+value
```

and nothing else, which means the attribute is not actually *set*. The above is called for the `s.name='abc'` expression, the `name` attribute is never set, so any future access to the `name` attribute is sent to `__getattr__` again.

Have `__setattr__` set the value in `__dict__` directly:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    print "__setattr__:" + value
    self.__dict__[name] = value
```

or make your class a [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (inherit from `object`), and you can re-use the base implementation with `super(c1, self).__setattr__(name, value)`.

As a side note: you implemented `c1.__get__`, presumably in an attempt to make the class a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). However, the descriptor protocol only applies to *class attributes*, not to instance attributes, and then only on *new-style classes*. Your class `d` is not a new-style class, and you used an instance attribute `c` to store the `c1` instance.